# how to assign a variable to each line from a repeating text pattern in python?

Tags: python, variables, text

I have a python **scraping** script to get infos about some upcomming concerts and it's the same text pattern everytime no matter how many concerts will appear, it means that each line will always be referring to a certain information such as this example (please note that there are no spaces between concerts, my data is exactly in this format):

```
01/01/99 9PM
Iron Maiden
Madison Square Garden 
New York City
01/01/99 9.30PM
The Doors
Staples Center
Los Angeles
01/02/99 8.45PM
Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg
Staples Center
Los Angeles
01/02/99 9PM
Diana Ross
City Hall
New York City ect...
```

For each line I need to assign it to a variable, so 4 variables in total:

```
time = all the 1st lines
name = all the 2nd lines
location = all the 3rd lines
city = all the 4th lines
```

Then loop through all the lines to catch the informations corresponding to each variables, such as getting all the dates from the 1st lines, all the names from the 2nd lines ect...

so far I haven't found any solutions yet, and I barely know anything about regex

I hope that you see the idea, don't hesitate if you have any questions thanks

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use regex:

```
string = '''01/01/99 9PM
Iron Maiden
Madison Square Garden 
New York City
01/01/99 9.30PM
The Doors
Staples Center
Los Angeles
01/02/99 8.45PM
Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg
Staples Center
Los Angeles
01/02/99 9PM
Diana Ross
City Hall
New York City
'''

lines = string.split('\n')
dates = [i for i in lines [0::4]]
bands = [i for i in lines [1::4]]
places = [i for i in lines [2::4]]
cities = [i for i in lines [3::4]]
```

This will give you a list of dates/bands/places/cities, which will be easier to work with.

If you want to turn them back into a string, you could do:

```
'; '.join(dates) #Do the same for all 4 variables
```

Which brings:

```
'01/01/99 9PM; 01/01/99 9.30PM; 01/02/99 8.45PM; 01/02/99 9PM; '
```

You could replace `'; '` with `' '` if you only want them to be space separated, or with whichever you like.

Comment: THANK YOU! it worked like a charm, I just have a follow-up question: the result of the variables are stored in list format ['...','...', ect], so how to get them back to a string format without messing everything up?

Comment: You could do `' ;'.join(dates)`. You can replace `;` with anything you want your string to be separated by

Comment: Edited my answer to add that

Comment: thank you so much, it worked perfectly again! Man, not all heroes wear caps hahaha my issue is finally solved, I have been searching on the web for hours... Have a nice day, bye

Comment: Thanks, just one last little thing if you don't mind: if I want to create another variable called 'hour' to only get the hour from the 'dates' variable, how would you do it please?

Comment: No problem, this should do: `hours = [i.split(' ')[1] for i in dates]`

Comment: It worked flawlessly again, many thanks for the big help and all the useful infos!

Comment: More robust way, using regex, but harder to understand: `hours = [re.search('(?<=\d{2} ).+',i).group(0) for i in dates]`

Comment: I hit again another roadblock grrr that sucks... after having all the bands name in my variable bands, what should I do to be able to get the nth band value individually in the list? To be clearer let's say I wanna compare the 1st and the 4th band, how to get those individual infos out? I guess it's kind of the same index situation like you presented at the beginning, with [0] representing the first value in the list, maybe a for loop to iterate over each value and pick only the one I need?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)s. Note that I put your data in a file called `input.txt`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

Entry = namedtuple("Entry", "time name location city")

with open('input.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

objects = [Entry(*lines[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 4)]
print(*objects, sep='\n')

for obj in objects:
    print(obj.name)
```

Output:

```
Entry(time='01/01/99 9PM', name='Iron Maiden', location='Madison Square Garden', city='New York City')
Entry(time='01/01/99 9.30PM', name='The Doors', location='Staples Center', city='Los Angeles')
Entry(time='01/02/99 8.45PM', name='Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg', location='Staples Center', city='Los Angeles')
Entry(time='01/02/99 9PM', name='Diana Ross', location='City Hall', city='New York City')
Iron Maiden
The Doors
Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg
Diana Ross
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls for slicing:

```
times = lines[0::4]
names = lines[1::4]
locations = lines[2::4]
cities = lines[3::4]
```

And now we can zip those lists into tuples:

```
events = zip(*[times, names, locations, cities])
```

With your sample data, this gives us

```
>>> list(events)
[('01/01/99 9PM', 'Iron Maiden', 'Madison Square Garden ', 'New York City'), ('01/01/99 9.30PM', 'The Doors', 'Staples Center', 'Los Angeles'), ('01/02/99 8.45PM', 'Dr Dre & Snoop Dogg', 'Staples Center', 'Los Angeles'), ('01/02/99 9PM', 'Diana Ross', 'City Hall', 'New York City')]
```

You can now process these tuples into any data structure that suits your use case best.

Comment: THANK YOU! it worked like a charm, I just have a follow-up question: the result of the variables are stored in list format ['...','...', ect], so how to get them back to a string format without messing everything up?

Comment: and what is the 2nd part with zip and tuples about please? what does it do?

Comment: @elcamino regarding `zip`: have a look at the documentation :) https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip For the other question, look at `str.join()` - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: thanks for the useful documentation, I'll definitely have a look on it